# If $I$ and $J$ are bounded intervals, then the intersection $I\cap J$ is also a bounded interval.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, bounded-variation

If $I$ and $J$ are bounded intervals, then the intersection $I\cap J$ is also a bounded interval.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $I$ and $J$ are bounded, we conclude that $I\subseteq[-M,M]$ and $J\subseteq[-N,N]$.

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $M > N$. Therefore $I\cap J\subseteq[-M,M]$.

Now it remains to prove that $I\cap J$ is an interval. There are three possibilities:

(a) $|I\cap J| = 0$

(b) $|I\cap J| = 1$

(c) $|I\cap J| > 1$.

In the first case, $I\cap J$ is the empty set, which is an interval.

In the second case, $I\cap J = \{a\}$, which is an interval as well.

In the third case, there are at least two points in $I\cap J$ (in fact, there are infinitely many).

If $x\in I\cap J$ and $y\in I\cap J$ such that $x < y$, we conclude that $x\in I$ and $y\in I$. Since $I$ is an interval, it results that $[x,y]\subseteq I$. Similar reasoning leads to the conclusion $[x,y]\subseteq J$. Hence $[x,y]\subseteq I\cap J$, and the result follows.

Can someone please double-check my reasoning?

Comment: Looks good to me, and I like the fact that you use the characterization of intervals as convex sets in $\Bbb R$.